# Non-fullscreen sections overflow handling

Tags: website-design, gui-design, responsive-design

#### The problem

I am creating a website with non-fullscreen-sections at the moment:

[image]

I am using a fullscreen-library to "switch" between the section when the user is scrolling. That way the sections will always be centered vertically on the screen (there also will be a possibility to deactivate this and scroll normally).

The problem now is the following: It might occur that the content for one section is too high for the section.

#### Possible solutions

There are two possible solutions for this problem:

1. Make the section scrollable
2. Don't fix the height of the section so it can adjust to its content

Both solution have disadvantages:

**Solution (1):** It might not be clear for every user that they have to scroll the section and not the whole page to see more content.

**Solution (2):** This is better from an UX-perspective in my opinion but it probably won't be as good as Solution 1 from an UI-perspective.

#### Question

Are there better solutions to this problem than the solutions I have thought about? If not, which solution is better and why?

Comment: Both solutions will work. If UI is one of the concerns. You can keep the scrollbar visible and customize it to fit your theme. Or you can explore providing an additional cue e.g "Scroll to view more".  This will help you address the concerns in your solution 01

Comment: I posted a detailed answer, but in my opinion, this question should include more details and clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll is ok when is needed.

How is relevant the fact the sections are not full-width? Your question is if you should use a scroll or not? If you have just a few lines of text, the scroll is not even needed and if you have a long text and the window width is small, the scroll is necessary, you don't have other options...

So basically your only issue is if the modal/ section should have a fixed/ flexible width depending on the length content. Considering what I said before, a scroll may be needed anyway, so keep a normal UI, with the modal width not depending on content (fixed-width or percent of the window width), but you can make it responsive, of course.

Also, that section seems a modal, but your explanations suggest is a page so keeping the content displayed without scroll is not so important, and more, navigating between pages with different can look strange and it is a lack of consistency.